# close popup opened by embeded Flash

Tags: javascript, flash, popup

I have my html where I embed third-party flash video by means of iframe. When I click play on the video a popup is opened.

I was wondering id there is a way to add a javascript function to my html that would close such a popup immediately when it is opened?

Answer (score 1):

No I'm afraid not. The popup window belongs to the iframe, which as you explained is third party content and thus on a different domain to the host site.
Security restrictions prevent javascript from actiong on windows or documents across domains. This is called the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).